# How to deploy from localhost to domain website

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, deployment

this seems to be very basic question, but since i am new to this area request your assistance. I have built a basic simple static website using angular and now i would like to deploy the website to internet using a domain through AWS. Currently, website is in my local and able to access it using localhost(http://localhost:4200), I would like understand the complete process on what all changes that are required for me to make deploy on internet. I understand that I need purchase a domain, which i will do however i am not exactly sure on the process that i need follow. How should i move my code to AWS? How should i maintain my dev environment vs prod environment? Is there a checklist which i need to follow?

Following points i have thought of:

1. Purchase a Domain
2. Create an EC2 instance (any other better option for my case since website is very small?)
3. install node and npm on that ec2 instance
4. copy the project to that ec2 instance

Kindly excuse me as I am quite new to angular and AWS itself.

Any kind of assistance is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you might want to show people what you have done so far and what is it that is preventing you from progressing.  For a static FE only, I would use S3, there are many tutorials explaining how to do it. Search for tutorials on deploying angular to aws and you will find plenty of them.

Comment: Try with Heroku or AWS. This is too generic question, you should follow Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: You can start with AWS lightsail - might be the easiest option. You can also try elastic beanstalk. If it is a Single Page App (which does not need any server, because you onl;y have static files) you can host through S3. And trust me you still have 100 different option how you can host your app.

Comment: Thanks everyone, just wanted to understand where to start from, as suggested by all of you went through S3 tutorials and was able to get some idea on how to proceed further. Will come back if i need more help or if am stuck on some point. Thanks again.